# How to edit .gitignore file/change .gitignore file rules through Terminal

Tags: git, terminal, edit

I'm new to Git.. I created a .gitignore file and added a line of folder name into the .gitignore file. Now I'm wondering if I want to make a change to the line where i specified the directory name, how should I achieve this, especially how to do this through Mac terminal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

That can be done using the vim editor.
Simply type `vi [path-to-file]\file` and you will open the vim terminal editor.
There's a lot (like a LOT) you can do with vim, but for your purposes:

- Press `a` to toggle the edit mode
- Edit stuff
- Press `Esc` to finish edit mode and toggle the command mode
- Press/type `:` to indicate you want to type a command
- Type and enter `wq` to save the changes and exit

I'm sorry if I'm "overdetailing" this steps but my first encounters with vim were a little unfortunate and closing the editor properly is not a trivial task.

Good luck!